# SQL to return NULL rows and corresponding next rows

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a mysql table where a column can have NULL values. Can someone help me with a SQL to return all the rows with the column is null, and as well as the next non-null rows?

Eg:

```
row 1, NULL
row 2, foo 1
row 3, foo 2
row 4, NULL
row 5, foo 3
row 6, foo 4
row 7, foo 5
row 8, NULL
row 9, foo 6
```

SQL will return:

```
row 1, NULL
row 2, foo 1
row 4, NULL
row 5, foo 3
row 8, NULL
row 9, foo 6
```

Comment: What if more than one consectutive rows have null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on your comment, update the answer. Actually for your case, you don't need any order by in the last, you need the native order of data I think. Probably I'm wrong, if so, please add order by as you need.

I borrow **@sgeddes's solution**, actually his solution fit your case best as far as I know. Only a tiny change is the second variable intialization, instead of NULL, give a non-null contanst value, then it can handle the first fews rows of data are not null scenario.

```
select col1, col2 
from (
  select *,
    @showRow:=IF(@prevCol2 is NULL,1,0) showRow,
    @prevCol2:=col2
  from yourtable
    join (SELECT @showRow:= 0, @prevCol2:= 'foo') t
  ) t
where showRow = 1 or col2 is null
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d71d/1)**

Comment: Is this not almost identical to my answer posted over an hour ago?

Comment: Oh, sorry, just validate your query, it already can handle the consecutive null scenario(+1). Yes, it is almost identical.

Comment: Hi ljh, thanks for this. I have added a few more rows at the beginning which are not null, but the SQL returns them. I would like the results to start with the first null row. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/714a3/1

Comment: If I removed the "join (SELECT \@rownumber:= 0) t", then it works. Can you explain why I need the "join (SELECT \@rownumber:= 0) t"?

Comment: Actually you don't really need that join in your case, it serves you better without join. I update @sgeddes's solution a little bit, it can also serve you, his idea is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like

```
select * from table t1
where t1.col2 = null
or (t1.col2 != null and exists (select 1 from table t2 where t1.col1 - 1 = t2.col1 and t2.col2 = null))
```

We return rows whos col2 is null, or if the col2 is null, we run a subquery to see if the row one before it (col1 - 1) has null in col2, if so we return that too.

Comment: This will only work if col1 has consecutive integers with no missing values.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk This is indeed true, and I hope it's explicit enough in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using user defined variables:

```
select col1, col2 
from (
  select *,
    @showRow:=IF(@prevCol2 is NULL,1,0) showRow,
    @prevCol2:=col2
  from yourtable
    join (SELECT @showRow:= 0, @prevCol2:= NULL) t
  ) t
where showRow = 1 or col2 is null
order by col1, col2
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b60d/4)